# Correlations and Hierachical Regression

Tags: regression, correlation, spss

For my dissertation I've carried out a hierarchical regression. My results have shown:

-correlations. 
Neuroticism is correlated non significantly .000 on SPSS to my dependent variable. 
Mood is non significantly correlated .13 on SPSS to my dependent variable.

However when I run my hierachical regression both neuroticism and mood are significant predictors of my dependent variable.

Is there any reason for this to happen? As they have a non significant correlation with the DV but predict it?
Also neuroticism and current mood are significantly correlated .253 with one another, could one mediate the other which is why this result has happened?

Answer (score 1):

Look up suppression effects in regression. When you have multiple predictors in a regression equation, the effects for each one are partial, which can be different than the simple bivariate relationships.